# How to get user name from object in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm a beginner in Laravel and I the following have migrations.

```php
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->bigInteger('company_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('company_id')->references('id')->on('companies')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->boolean('enable')->default(0);
    $table->string('name', 120)->nullable();
    $table->string('surname', 120)->nullable();
    $table->string('email', 120)->unique();
    $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
    $table->string('password');
    $table->boolean('enable_map')->default(0);
    $table->rememberToken();
    $table->timestamps();
    $table->engine = "InnoDB";
});

Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
    $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
    $table->Integer('rating');
    $table->text('content');
    $table->dateTime('date_time');
    $table->string('ip', 25);
    $table->engine = "InnoDB";
});
```

**User.php**

```
class User extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail
{
    use Notifiable;
    use psCMS\Presenters\UserPresenter;

    public static $roles = [];

    protected $fillable = ['company_id', 'enable', 'name', 'surname', 'email', 'email_verified_at', 'password', 'counter', 'url_address',  'isCompany', 'isMailing', 'content', 'nip1', 'business1', 'phone1', 'street1', 'number1', 'postal_code1', 'city1', 'country_id1', 'provincial_id1', 'nip2', 'business2', 'phone2', 'street2', 'number2', 'postal_code2', 'city2', 'country_id2', 'provincial_id2', 'nip3', 'business3', 'phone3', 'street3', 'number3', 'postal_code3', 'city3', 'country_id3', 'provincial_id3', 'cash', 'lng', 'lat', 'enable_map', 'remember_token', 'created_at', 'updated_at', 'last_login_at', 'last_login_ip' ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    public function photos()
    {
        return $this->morphMany('App\Photo', 'photoable');
    }

    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Role');
    }

    public function comments()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\Comments');
    }

    public function hasRole(array $roles)
    {
        foreach($roles as $role)
        {
            if(isset(self::$roles[$role]))
            {
                if(self::$roles[$role])  return true;

            } else {
                self::$roles[$role] = $this->roles()->where('name', $role)->exists();
                if(self::$roles[$role]) return true;
            }

        }

        return false;
    }

    public function loginHistory()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\UserLoginHistory');
    }
}
```

**Comments.php**

```
class Comments extends Model
{
    protected $quarded = [];
    public $timestamps = false;

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

When I make this code:

```
Comments::where('content','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')->orWhere('id','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')->orderBy($sortColumn, $sortMethod)->paginate(25);
```

I don't have the info about the user. I have only values from comments. Why How can I get info about user, which add these comments? I would like to display a list of comments along with information about the user.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Comments::with('user')->where('content','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')->orWhere('id','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')->orderBy($sortColumn, $sortMethod)->paginate(25);

Comment: Don't post code-only answers; explain what the code does and why it works. And please format it correctly (4 spaces for a code block)

Comment: @trafficker, can you please confirm if the above solution works. Based on the code on your question, it shouldn't.

Answer (score 2):

> I haven't info about user. I have only values from comments. Why?

Because you are doing the query only on the model Comments

> How can I get info about user, which add this comments?

Add with user to the query:

```
$comments_with_user_info = Comments::with('user')->where('content','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')->orWhere('id','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')->orderBy($sortColumn, $sortMethod)->paginate(25);
```

> I would like to display a list of comments along with information about the user.

You can get the name in this way ( for example in blade):

```
@foreach($comments_with_user_info as $comment)
    {{ $comment->user->name }}
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 2):

1. As a best practice, the class name should take the singular form of the table name. You can read about this at https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#defining-models.
2. You should be able to access the `user()` relationship by eager-loading it using `with()`.

```
$comments = Comments::with('user')
                ->where('content','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
                ->orWhere('id','LIKE','%'.$query.'%')
                ->orderBy($sortColumn, $sortMethod)->get();

                // or paginate method
```

3. What you are retrieving is a collection. So you will have to loop through the `comments` to get the `user` object

```
foreach($comment in $comments){
    $userObj = $comments->user;
    $email = $userObj->email;
    //...etc here
}
```

Comment: The comment on auto-guessing table names is incorrect; Laravel knows not to append an `s` if the name ends in an `s`; valid example is `Series`; it doesn't look for `seriess` if you omit `protected $table = "series";`, but `Series` is both the singular and plural form. Everything else is correct, but somewhat already covered in  porloscerros Ψ's answer. I agree it should be `Comment` and not `Comments`, but it still works in this form.

Comment: @TimLewis, thanks. that is good to know. I will edit my answer to remove the info regarding auto-gessing